# WM_KEYDOWN message not sent

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, spy++

I've been trying to track down a bug in my program. I noticed that whenever I am holding down the up and left arrow keys and press the spacebar, a WM_KEYDOWN message with a WPARAM of VK_SPACE is never received or processed by my WndProc.

I was a bit curious, so I opened up Spy++ and started viewing the messages sent to my window. I noticed that when I am holding down the left and up arrow keys and press another key, say A, the WM_KEYDOWN (as well as a WM_CHAR) message is sent to my window.

But if I'm holding down the up and left arrow keys and press the spacebar, a WM_KEYDOWN message for the spacebar hit is not sent to my window.

What is the reason for this? Could anyone confirm this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your keyboard is doing what is called [ghosting](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx). This is normal for the majority of keyboards used by people today. It's wired up so that it's a lot cheaper to produce, and as a result, things like this happen consistently.

Basically when three keys in the same row/column are pressed at once, they cannot all be uniquely identified, causing at least one not to go through. The only thing you can do is buy an anti-ghosting keyboard, or redesign your controls to avoid conflicts.

On a personal level, I found out about this a day or two before I presented my game and ended up having to make the controls something like P1: SZXC and space and P2: /789 and +. It really is a good thing to know beforehand.

Comment: I think that's it. Thanks for the link. It's a shame, because the arrows keys and spacebar seem like a natural fit.

Comment: @user974967, indeed, I was surprised as well. Right after reading that, I tried to find a game that used controls that conflicted like that, but was surprised that I couldn't really find any. I gained a lot more respect for game programmers that day. I guess that's one reason WASD is so popular, and people don't even know it.

Comment: WSAD is also popular as most people are right handed thus it's a more convenient place for your non-mouse hand to rest. If you have more than 3 keys used together you may want to re-evaluate your user input interface as well as I can't think of any game where you press 3+ keys at once.

Comment: @AJG85, exactly, that's another reason. But consider moving diagonally while shooting.

Comment: @chris Ah yes I forgot about the days of DOS side scrollers for a second. Most keyboards will support up to four keys at least but I can't remember the last time I made game without mouse input.